# Should I update all hrefs and src when doing a pushState?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pushstate

If I'm about to call a `pushState` but I want to preserve all the relative links, images, stylesheets, ect, I do something like this so far:

```
$('[href]').each(function() { 
    if (!/^#/.test(this.href)) this.href = this.href;
});
$('[src]').each(function() { this.src = this.src });
```

My question is: will this work cross browser? Do I need to do `$(this).attr('href') = this.href` ?

Is this necessary? Is there another way to do this? Is this the best way to do it? And is it always going to work?

Comment: I tested it out so far on FF IE and Chrome

Comment: Inside a jQuery callback, `this` is the element itself, where as outside of a callback you need to use the selector and `attr` combo.

Comment: @rxgx: I don't think you understood how the code above works

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to achieve, but `this.src = this.src` is effectively equal to 1=1; It does nothing.

Comment: @JoshuaBoshi: [**See here for what it does**](http://jsfiddle.net/xJxGD/)

Comment: Not sure what you're doing, but it DOES NOT work cross-browser: just tried it in FF and Opera and got different results for the 'after' alert.

Comment: Can't see why it wouldn't work for every browser that supports pushState. Although putting relative links in a pushState enabled page sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: @SeanHogan: well I'm trying to make a ajax navigation plugin

Comment: @dalbaeb: Which browser did it not change the path to absolute?

Comment: @qwertymk: Never mind, same behaviour in both browsers. Only when you click on 'run', the URL is different. So the second alert on page load: `http://fiddle.jshell.net/xJxGD/show/relative/path`, and after clicking 'run': `http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/relative/path`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pushState` changes the relative path of the current document.

You can break or avoid breaking relative sources depending on how you do the relative path.

The `./*` pattern does relative paths off the current path, but plan old `/*` will always start at the path root and would be unaffected by `pushState` changes.

```
./this/would/break.jpg

/this/wont.jpg
```

Comment: But can we safely assume that any resource that is already parsed or rendered will not be affected? E.g. if I have an existing <img src="static/flower.png"> element on a page and it is already rendered, will pushing a new state break it?